# Скрыть, убрать подобный элемент у изображения

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом возможно через css, убрать подобное у изображения при путом src

Comment: Вам ведь на самом деле не это нужно? Просто удалить img с пустым src пойдёт?

Comment: `[src=""]`, вот вам селектор, а каким способом скрывать решайте вы :)

Comment: Не удалить, убрать это, подфиксить что на скриншоте. Совсем скрывать img это не выход

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно "убрать подобное у изображения при пустом src", то всё просто:

```css
[src=""] {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Pb9F.png" rel="nofollow noreferrer">
  <img src="" alt="введите сюда описание изображения">
</a>
```

Однако вместе с этим исчезнет и атрибут `alt="описание"`. Так что, если вам нужно не только скрыть (рыбку съесть), но и вернуть на место описание, то без JS не обойтись. Потребуется сделать как-то так:

```js
// получить все "a > img" с пустым атрибутом [src]
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('a > img[src=""]');
// перебрать их и назначить родителю <a> атрибут 'data-alt'
for (let el of elements) {
  let alt = el.getAttribute('alt');
  let parent = el.closest('a');
  parent.setAttribute('data-alt', alt);
}
```

```css
/* скрыть пустышки целиком*/
a > img[src=""] {
  display: none;
}
/* воссоздать описание */
a::before {
  content: attr(data-alt);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Pb9F.png" rel="nofollow noreferrer">
  <img src="" alt="введите сюда описание изображения">
</a>
```

Comment: А если я вообще не указу `src`, тогда что будете делать :)? А ещё добавьте изображение где всё указано, так непонятно работает у вас что-то или нет.

Comment: А вы тут при чём? Может мне за него и весь остальной код написать? Я ответил на вопрос? Ответил. Люди учится на ошибках, а не на готовых решениях. Столкнётся, поймёт, что нужны и прочие нюансы в виде hasAttribute. Не исключено, что ему JS вообще не впёрся, поскольку чел явно не очень владеет предметом.

Comment: А вы разве это уже не сделали...? Да, ответили, но не учли всех кейсов. Справедливо, но вы именно такое решение и написали. Не нужны, достаточно средств CSS, советую вам подробнее ознакомится с псведо-классами. Надеюсь мой комментарий был полезным для вас.

Comment: Советую вам кстати удалить часть с решением на JS, всё-таки это не совсем подходит под вопрос. Вопрос можно отредактировать кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1474025/edit).